# Spring boot is not able to resolve the properties used in XML configurations when using cloud-starter-config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-properties

I'm creating a spring boot application A, using annotations and XML configuration both and config-starter-config to fetch the application properties from config-server. 
Application is having XML beans file importing other beans XML from the imported **module B**.

As soon as, I'm adding spring-cloud-starter-config, the application fails to resolve the properties getting used by the **module B**. Even able to fetch the properties properly from the config-server.

**Error**:

> o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionName' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Subscriber.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/IF.jar!/META-INF/jms-config-ref.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: ${InitialContext} [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${InitialContext}]

When creating a setup to run the application **without** spring-cloud-starter-config and providing properties from `application.properties` then it works fine.

**Update:** The main xml is getting loaded using 
`@ImportResource("classpath:spring-sub-config.xml")`

And the starting content inside

```
<beans .. xsd ns ..>
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///${CONFIG_PATH}/Subscriber.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sub, com.inte" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/inte-cmn-ref.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/jms-config-ref.xml" />
...
</beans>
```

I want these beans to resolve the properties pulled from config-server. 
Any suggestions, how we can make the initialization of **Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean** lazy. 
PS: I've already tried `lazy-init="true"` property.

Comment: How are those XML files being loaded. Currently there is too little information to give you an answer.

Comment: Updated the question with asked information. Using spring-boot-2.0.7-RELEASE version.

Comment: Remove the `<context:property-placeholder` and instead use an `@PropertySource` on your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.